# Can we use mapcreator.here.com data with android sdk?

Tags: here-api

The area where our customers are using our application made with the here sdk contains mapping errors. We are using the mapcreator web application to fix the errors but the changes do not appear immediatelly in the application as they need to be reviewed before being integrated on the real map server.

Is there a way to export the mapcreator (unreviewed) maps in the map format the sdk is using so that changes would be reflected immediately ?

If not, how long does it take for changes in mapcreator to be reflected in the maps downloaded with MapLoader ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will take sometime before the map creator data is propagated to our commercial maps.

However, you can use our [MapRasterTile](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-urlmaprastertilesourcebase.html) APIs to replace just the areas you are interested in with data from MapCreator. Please let us know if you require additional information or a sample.

Comment: Ok, a sample would be nice. Is there a way to persist these tiles in order to use them offline ? Will routing and navigation consider the new routes as well ?

Comment: Routing and Navigation will not consider the map creator changes because the raster tiles are for display only. Let me find a sample to get the tiles and will get back to you.

Comment: Displaying these tiles without being able to use them for routing is of little use to me as I'm building a navigation solution. Is there a way to use mapcreator data for routing ?

Comment: Currently no, this use case is not supported with the mobile SDK. Please contact HERE technical support to see if we can help you out!

Comment: It has been a month since I made the map change on mapcreator and it has not been reflected yet. When will it be ? Is there a fastest way to have the production map updated ?

Comment: Does the new edits show on HERE.com? If so, please use the map loader APIs to update the map on the device.

Comment: No they are not showing on HERE.com yet (after 1 month!!). What can I do ? The edit is just at the exit of the truck station of my customer and it's giving false directions at the beginning of every route...

Comment: Please send an email to technical customer support. This data has not been rolled out yet.